# log4j reset properties back to original as in log4j.properties file

Tags: java, configuration, log4j

In my application, I defined log4j.properites as follows

```
log4j.appender.email=org.apache.log4j.net.SMTPAppender
log4j.appender.email.Subject=email Notification
```

later in the program i am dynamically changing the subject to

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("log4j.appender.email.Subject", "Test Completed");
```

After I use this variable, I wan to reset this back to original on file. so I did this

```
LogManager.resetConfiguration();
PropertyConfigurator.configure(prop);
```

But, later in the code whenever I use this subject property it is giving its value as 'Test Completed'. Any suggestion to reset configuration is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I guess the possible cause of the problem is that you have Logger constructed after you change subject, so it gets Appender with that subject. Later when you reset config you don't recreate you Logger instance which is stuck with old email appender

Comment: Yeah i've checked the resetConfiguration source and it has nothing to do with appenders, while PropertyConfigurator.configure is just used to read configuration - not reconfigure logger instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in my comments above both

```
LogManager.resetConfiguration();
PropertyConfigurator.configure(prop);
```

don't reconfigure already existing Logger instances, so that they still use your old EmailAppender. In order to make changes to take effect you should recreate loggers.
If it's not possible (your loggers are static final fields for example), you can create a simple Logger wrapper, which will register itself with some listener, that will notify on configuration change, so that wrapper can create fresh logger instance

Comment: @Scoff: I did this But having the same issue that log4j is using the dynamically changed content. I achieved this by reistansiating the properties file every time I change the properties.

Comment: May its not suggestible to load the same class many times. Is there any alternate for this

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer (I know); But you can do a reset without explicit `LogManager.resetConfiguration();`

> **Resetting Hierarchy**
>
> The hierarchy will be reset before configuration when log4j.reset=true is present in the properties file.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PropertyConfigurator.html