# How to disable log4j logging from Java code

Tags: java, log4j

I use a legacy library that writes logs using log4j. My default log4j.properties file directs the log to the console, but in some specific functions of my main program, I would like to disable logging altogether (from all classes).

I tried this:

```
Logger.getLogger(BasicImplementation.class.getName()).setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

where "BasicImplementation" is one of the main classes that does logging, but it didn't work - the logs are still written to the console.

Here is my log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=warn, stdout
log4j.logger.ac.biu.nlp.nlp.engineml=info, logfile
log4j.logger.org.BIU.utils.logging.ExperimentLogger=warn

log4j.appender.stdout = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern = %-5p %d{HH:mm:ss} [%t]: %m%n

log4j.appender.logfile = ac.biu.nlp.nlp.log.BackupOlderFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfile.append=false
log4j.appender.logfile.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfile.layout.ConversionPattern = %-5p %d{HH:mm:ss} [%t]: %m%n
log4j.appender.logfile.File = logfile.log
```

Comment: It is likely that you have to disable the root logger, but please post your `log4j.properties`/`log4j.xml` first.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So, you have 3 loggers defined, including the root:

```
log4j.rootLogger=warn, stdout
log4j.logger.ac.biu.nlp.nlp.engineml=info, logfile
log4j.logger.org.BIU.utils.logging.ExperimentLogger=warn
```

Unfortunately, to disable them programatically, you need to specify ALL OF THEM in the code:

```java
Logger.getLogger("ac.biu.nlp.nlp.engineml").setLevel(Level.OFF);
Logger.getLogger("org.BIU.utils.logging.ExperimentLogger").setLevel(Level.OFF);
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7884961/838434) how to reset it back to what's set in the config file.

Answer (score 9):

If you wanna achieve perfect silence (like for a quiet command line tool), you can  always use the [NullAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/varia/NullAppender.html).

```
Logger.getRootLogger().removeAllAppenders();
Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(new NullAppender());
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
Logger.getRootLogger().setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

to disable any logging in java code

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps like that:

`Logger.getRootLogger().shutdown();`

Answer (score 1):

In the version 1.8 of java.util.logging.Logger the correctly form is:

`Logger.getLogger("").setLevel(Level.OFF);`

Comment: The question asked about Log4j, not java.util.logging.

Answer (score 1):

For newer log4j versions, you may consider to call:

`LogManager.shutdown();`

Instead of:

`Logger.shutdown();`

which is deprecated. But it still makes the same thing:

> Calling this method will safely close and remove all appenders in all the categories including root contained in the default hierachy.

Answer (score -2):

You could try TO disable it changing your log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=off, stdout
#log4j.logger.ac.biu.nlp.nlp.engineml=info, logfile
#log4j.logger.org.BIU.utils.logging.ExperimentLogger=warn

...
```

Ref:
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html#OFF

Answer (score -2):

Add the following to your log file

```
log4j.logger.com.class.with.package.BasicImplementation = off, logfiledata

log4j.appender.logfiledata = ac.biu.nlp.nlp.log.BackupOlderFileAppender
log4j.appender.logfiledata.append=false
log4j.appender.logfiledata.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.logfiledata.layout.ConversionPattern = %-5p %d{HH:mm:ss} [%t]: %m%n
log4j.appender.logfiledata.File = logfiledata.log
```

If the above will not stop if from logging, it will at least log all the data from BasicImplementation class to a separate file.