# How do i stop JtaTransactionManager log messages in console?

Tags: spring, logging, jboss, jmstemplate

I have integrated JmsTemplate with Jboss 6.2 and HornetQ everything works fine.

I have added

```
<bean id="messageListener" class="com.poc.services.jmstemplate.Consumer" />

    <bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
        <property name="destination" ref="defaultDestination" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
    </bean>
```

and after that, i get the following messages continuously for every second

```
16:07:30,734 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (jmsContainer-1) Creating new transaction with name [jmsContainer]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
16:07:32,240 DEBUG [org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager] (jmsContainer-1) Initiating transaction commit
```

how do i stop this?

Comment: which is your logging framework?

Comment: @Lovababu hi thanks for the reply, it is log4j

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it should work.

```
<!-- Loggers to filter out various class paths -->

<logger name="org.springframework.transaction.jta">
      <level value="OFF"/> 
</logger>
```

Refer: [how-to-disable-log4j-logging-from-java-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709357/how-to-disable-log4j-logging-from-java-code)